# how to adjust date constructor in substr javascript

Tags: javascript

if you look at my date validation when i come to test if it is in the past it works although the date constructor expects a zero date month so how do i subtract one from the substring value representing the month (one from the result, not the position)

```
//start of datefield
var dateformat=/^(?:(?:31\/(?:0[13578]|1[02])|(?:29|30)\/(?:0[13-9]|1[012])|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))\/[2-9]\d{3}|29\/02\/(?:[2-9]\d(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))$/;
if (!date.match(dateformat))
{
      errors.push("format incorrect use dd/mm/yyyy make sure you are entering correct days to the month remember 30 days have september, april, june & november, only 28 days in february unless leap year next is 2016");

}
var today = new Date();

var courseYear =date.substr(6,4) // use substr or substring to capture the last four digits
var courseMonth =date.substr(3,2) // use substr or substring to capture the four and fifth digits
var courseDay = date.substr(0,2)//e the first and second digits

var dateToCompare = new Date(courseYear, courseMonth, courseDay);

if (dateToCompare < today) {
  errors.push("this date is in the past"); 

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string to a number?

Comment: Are you seriously trying to detect leap years in regex???

Comment: no sorry basically my var coursemonth  constructor expects a 0 based month so jan is 0 feb is 1 etc so when i do check to see if the date is in the past and i enter say 25/05/2013 this passes due to the scripting thinking that 5 is actually june . so i wanted to know how to  deduct one from the substr value representing the month

Answer (score 3):

> so how do i subtract one

With the [subtraction operator "`-`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) and the number literal "`1`". It also has the benefit of converting the string to a number before. For year and day, you might use the unary plus to do that conversion explicitly (though the `Date` constructor does it implicitly):

```
new Date(+courseYear, courseMonth-1, +courseDay);
```